# Nuxtjs Page does not refresh nor can be accessed if URL does not end with a trailing slash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, seo

I am having an issue in my nuxtjs application refreshing the page `(F5)`.

Let's say im in this page `https://example.com/foo/bar` (which equals to `https://example.com/foo/bar/index.html`) and I press the refresh button the page doesn't reload after some time I get a `this site can't be reached` error.

But when I put a slash `/` at the end it reloads perfectly.

Also, I cannot access the page directly without a slash at the end or `/index.html` and when I do it changes to `https://example.com/foo/bar`.

Any idea on how to fix this?

I do not want to use `router: { trailingSlash: false },` because I read that is going to affect my SEO.

I also added this: [NuxtJS Static generated HTML page does not load Javascript when calling /index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719727/nuxtjs-static-generated-html-page-does-not-load-javascript-when-calling-index-h) but it did not solved this issue tho it solved another one I had.

my `nuxt-config.js`:

```
router: {
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719727/nuxtjs-static-generated-html-page-does-not-load-javascript-when-calling-index-h
  extendRoutes(routes) {
    routes.forEach((route) => {
      // When options.generate.subFolders is true (default)
      const alias = route.path.length > 1 ? `${route.path}/index.html` : '/index.html'

      // When options.generate.subFolders is false
      // const normalizedRoute = route.path.replace(/\/$/, '') // Remove trailing slashes if they exist
      // const alias =
      //   route.path.length > 1 ? `${normalizedRoute}.html` : '/index.html'

      route.alias = alias
    })
  },
},
```

**Update 21/07/2021**

I added the
`router: { trailingSlash: true }` and also install the `@nuxtjs/redirect-module`

```
['@nuxtjs/redirect-module', {
      redirect: [
        {
          from: '^.*(?<!/)$',
          to: (from, req) => req.url + '/',
          statusCode: 301
        }]
    }]
```

but the issue still persists. Locally it works fine but when deployed in the server it does not.

Comment: Your issue here is not on the `router` key but broad. Also, you need to use **either** `npm run build` OR `npm run generate`. Not both.

Comment: @kissu I do not have anything else related to routing in the `nuxt-config.js` file! tagret is set to `static` but other than that all the rest are the standard ones

Comment: This should work as expected if you have a fresh and unmodified project. Do you have a Github repo? Did you tried to host it on Netlify, just to see if it works there?

Comment: @kissu no, as I said it is hosted on AWS servers as per clients requirements!

Comment: For **debug purposes**, can you see if it works on `netlify.com/drop`? Generate your project and drop the `dist` directory there. It will remove one of the possible issues? At the end, this kind of bug should not happen and I don't see how this one is not working. Hence, to go faster, we could remove the fact that the bug is coming from your hosting configuration. You can remove it from Netlify afterwards. If this one does not work, we could then inspect more deeply your whole `nuxt.config.js` file and the other components.